# SimpleCursorAdapter set progressbar value and display in each item in listview Android

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to bind data from my database columns to android view items.
In my customListView.xml , I added progressbar and I'd like to set maxvalue and progress in this progressbar from my database columns.

Code for simplecursoradapter:

```
String[] from = new String[] {category.KEY_NAME,"MAX","PROGRESS"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.l_cat,progressbar4.setMax,progressbar4.setProgress};

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.customListView,cursor,from,to,0);
```

EDIT. I changed code for simplecursoradapter:

```
    String[] from = new String[] {category.KEY_NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.l_category};


    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.customListView,cursor,from,to,0);
    adapter.setViewBinder(new CustomViewBinder());
    listCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
```

customListView.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/selektor"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">


<TextView
        android:id = "@+id/l_cat"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:text = "NAME"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT. Added ViewBinder class.
I've tried to use SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder, but I don't know what's wrong that it doesn't set up my progressbar values.

This is how I implement ViewBinder:

```
private class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder{
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if(view.getId()==R.id.progressBar4)
            {
                ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) view;
                    progress.setMax(cursor.getColumnIndex("MAX"));
                    progress.setProgress(cursor.getColumnIndex("PROGRESS"));
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: setup `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` in your adapter

Comment: I edited my question and added what I did. Can you check and tell me what's wrong with it. Thank you.

Comment: does it even compile? in `new int[] {R.id.l_cat,progressbar4.setMax,progressbar4.setProgress};` what is `progressbar4`? and `progressbar4.setMax` and `progressbar4.setProgress`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I tried it at the beginning, but @pskin said to use ViewBinder, and I did so. I edited my question and you can see how my simplecursoradapter looks like now. I don't use `progressbar4` anymore. It still doesn't work with this ViewBinder class

Comment: `from` and `to` arrays have only one element so only one `TextView` is mapped by your adapter

Comment: Ok, but I used `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` to bind values from progressbar. Do I have to do something else to set progressbar values in each item in listview?

Comment: make those arrays to have two items